# Open specific url when successful pay - paypal button

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, button, paypal

I created Smart paypal button and got this code

```html
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=EUR" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'buynow',
          
      },
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                      value: '13.88'
                  }
              }]
          });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

I am wondering, is there function to open specific url after successful payment to add in onApprove function after alert? Will it work like that?

Will window.open() work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign). The syntax:

```
location.assign(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ["location.replace()"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace).

You can additionally get the order id from the details object and use that as a get parameter in the redirect url. This allows you to verify the transaction on the next page, preventing the user from just directly calling the "success" url.